# Jackson FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES to false not working

Tags: java, jackson, thrift

I am trying to make thrift deserialization for jackason backward compatible

```
ObjectMapper mapper = getObjectMapper(false /* pretty */);
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.READ_UNKNOWN_ENUM_VALUES_AS_NULL, true); // This works

// This doesn't work
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);


MapLikeType t = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructMapLikeType(LinkedHashMap.class, keyClass, valueClass);
return mapper.readValue(content, t);
```

`valueClass` is of the following type

```
public class MyThrift implements org.apache.thrift.TBase<MyThrift, MyThrift._Fields>, java.io.Serializable, Cloneable, Comparable<MyThrift> {
```

I keep getting

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Can not construct instance of com.MyThrift$_Fields from String value 'MY_ID': value not one of declared Enum instance names
```

if I use `FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES`

But I don't get the same error if I use `READ_UNKNOWN_ENUM_VALUES_AS_NULL` , can someone point me a direction on why using `FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES` not work?

Does jackason bind not support `FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES` for thrift ?

Comment: Could you show your `JSON` payload and `MyThrift` class?

Answer (score 2):

`FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES` is for the property names of your object.  `READ_UNKNOWN_ENUM_VALUES_AS_NULL` is for the property value.

So if you had a JSON string that looked like this:

```
{
"property1": "ENUM_ONE",
"property2": "ENUM_TWO"
}
```

You would use `FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES`, for example, if your value object didn't have `getProperty2`/`setProperty2`, whereas you would use`READ_UNKNOWN_ENUM_VALUES_AS_NULL` if `ENUM_TWO` did not exist in your enum.