# With all configurations DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, jackson2

I tried all the solutions provided on these below SO threads:

[Jackson FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES to false not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54661770/jackson-fail-on-unknown-properties-to-false-not-working)

[jackson Unrecognized field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8409567/jackson-unrecognized-field)

[Spring Boot Web- Set FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES to false in Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21262378/spring-boot-web-set-fail-on-unknown-properties-to-false-in-jackson)

And around 10 more similar SO threads.

Here is my Spring Boot application:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
public class MyApplication {

    @Autowired
    private WebClient webClient;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);

    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner demo() {
        return (args) -> {
            getDetails("abcd12345");

        };
    }

    private void getDetails(String nodeId) throws IOException {
        Mono<String> mono = webClient.get().uri("/end/point").retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class);
        System.out.println(mono.block());
        final ObjectNode node = objectMapper().readValue(mono.block(), ObjectNode.class);
        System.out.println(node.get("parent").get("properties").get("nonExisting:keyhere").asText());  // NPE here
    }

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        return Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.json().featuresToEnable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder objectMapperBuilder() {
        Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
        builder.failOnUnknownProperties(false);
        return builder;
    }

}
```

And my application.properties file has:

```
spring.jackson.deserialization.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES=false
```

Output:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.springbatch.parallel.processing.Application.getDetails(MyApplication .java:43)
```

But still I am getting NullPointerException (NPE) for non-existing key. I am trying to disable FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES. What I am missing here?

Comment: Unknown properties don't cause an NPE. Show the full output.

Comment: Added the output. Thanks

Comment: It seems to me that one of the `get()` calls in `node.get("parent").get("properties").get("nonExisting:keyhere")` is null, hence the NPE.

Comment: I understand. Question is - how to avoid it? As in my situation, for few calls there is some value present and in some cases its not. When the key is present, there is no error whatsoever.

Comment: Please check my answer below.

Comment: The easiest way is to use [`path()`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#path(java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to cope with the possibility of `null` being returned by any of the calls in that chained method call as follows:

```java
private void getDetails(String nodeId) throws IOException {
    Mono<String> mono = webClient.get().uri("/end/point").retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class);
    System.out.println(mono.block());
    final ObjectNode node = objectMapper().readValue(mono.block(), ObjectNode.class);
    JsonNode parentNode = node.get("parent");
    if (parentNode != null) {
        JsonNode parentPropertiesNode = parentNode.get("properties");
        if (parentPropertiesNode != null) {
            JsonNode nonExistingKeyNode = parentPropertiesNode.get("nonExisting:keyhere");
            if (nonExistingKeyNode != null) {
                System.out.println(nonExistingKeyNode.asText());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally, avoid at all costs using `block()` in a Reactive stack. By doing this you are wasting all the benefits of using Spring WebFlux. Here is a very interesting online resource about common mistakes while using the Reactive stack: https://medium.com/javarevisited/five-mistakes-to-avoid-in-reactive-java-786927ffd2f6.

Comment: I totally get your point @Joao Dias. But the question remains why FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES config is not working?

Comment: That has no effect when you deserialize to `ObjectNode`. `FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES` has only an effect if were deserializing your JSON to a custom Java class that actually matches your JSON. In the case that that JSON would include properties that were not included in your Java model then Jackson would simply ignore them with `FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES = false`. It has nothing to do with the way you are using Jackson.

Comment: Ah got it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for editing my answer and actually fixing a bug in it ;)